# Spring MVC: Receive radio button values

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I need to receive and unknown number of Radio Buttons values on my controller.

The radio buttons are generated and may vary... So i need a way to receive as many as the user send. How can i achieve this?

View (using Velocity):

```
...
#foreach( $f in $model.fields )
<input type="radio" name="rd_$f.name" value="S" checked="checked"/> S
<input type="radio" name="rd_$f.name" value="C" /> C
#end
...
```

This will generate X number of radio buttons sets...
I Need to receive it on my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{e}/{id1}/{id2}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView salvar(@PathVariable(value = "e") String e,
            @PathVariable(value = "id1") Long id1, 
            @PathVariable(value = "id2") Long id2,
            //MY RADIO BUTTONS ARRAY HERE!
      ) {

          ...

    }
```

**UPDATE:**

The html generated is something like:

```
...
<input type="radio" name="rd_1" value="S" checked="checked"/> S
<input type="radio" name="rd_1" value="C" /> C
...
<input type="radio" name="rd_2" value="S" checked="checked"/> S
<input type="radio" name="rd_2" value="C" /> C
...
<input type="radio" name="rd_n" value="S" checked="checked"/> S
<input type="radio" name="rd_n" value="C" /> C
...
```

So i can't just bind to a [] on the controller, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind using `@RequestParam(value="radio_name") String[] radioCheckedValues` as one more attribute in your spring controller.

**EDIT**
The only way a server can know about what's coming from the client is using the name. You can use the `request.getParameterNames`.

Pseudo code...

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList();
Enumeration<String> enumeration = req.getParameterNames();
while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
    String parameterName = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
    if(parameterName.startsWith("rd_")) {
        values.add(req.getParameter(parameterName));
    }
}
```

Comment: i updated my question, see if you can see the problem now! thanks

Comment: Thanks very much! This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[]` in the name to group each radiobox in one array:

```
#foreach( $f in $model.fields )
<input type="radio" name="radio[]" value="S" checked="checked"/> S
<input type="radio" name="radio[]" value="C" /> C
#end
```

Then read this array in the controller.

Edit:

To retrieve values use (loop on each array):

```
String[] params = request.getParameterValues("rd_n");
```

Comment: i updated my question, see if you can see the problem now! thanks

Comment: You can create an array per group using name="rd_n[]".